# How to reorder columns based on regex?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'foo':[1, 2], 'bar': [3, 4], 'xyz': [5, 6]})

   bar  foo  xyz
0    3    1    5
1    4    2    6
```

I now want to put the column that contains `oo` at the first position (i.e. at 0th index); there is always only one column with this pattern.

I currently solve this using `filter` twice and a `concat`:

```
pd.concat([df.filter(like='oo'),  df.filter(regex='^((?!(oo)).)*$')], axis=1)
```

which gives the desired output:

```
   foo  bar  xyz
0    1    3    5
1    2    4    6
```

I am wondering whether there is a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
df[sorted(df, key = lambda x: x not in df.filter(like="oo").columns)]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use list comprehensions only, join lists together and select by `subset`:

```
a = [x for x in df.columns if 'oo' in x]
b = [x for x in df.columns if not 'oo' in x]

df = df[a + b]
print (df)
   foo  bar  xyz
0    1    3    5
1    2    4    6
```

Comment: Mmh, I used a bad example, as I am interested in an actual regex not just for a simple `in` solution.

Comment: then use `re` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pop`:

```
cols = list(df)
col_oo = [col for col in df.columns if 'oo' in col]
cols.insert(0, cols.pop(cols.index(col_oo[0])))
df = df.ix[:, cols]
```

Or using `regex`:

```
col_oo = [col for col in cols if re.search('oo', col)]
```